# How to assign identifiers to all HTML elements of a particular type?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

My site embeds posts from an RSS feed, and some of these posts contain `<audio>` elements. In a separate JS file, I want to be able to assign each `<audio>` element on the page a unique identifier based on their src attribute so that they can be handled separately. Of course, I don't know in advance how many `<audio>` elements there will be, nor what the names of their src attributes will be. So basically I will have something like this:

```
<audio src="1.mp3"></audio>
<audio src="2.mp3"></audio>
<audio src="3.mp3"></audio>

...

<audio src="X.mp3"></audio>
```

... where the filenames of the mp3s are unknown in advance. So I want my JS file to be able to scan through the HTML, and each time it encounters an `<audio>` element, add it to a list with some sort of unique identifier so that they can all be told apart.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what research you've done and what attempts you've made based on that research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a `for` loop solution.

```js
let audio = document.querySelectorAll('audio');

for (let i = 0; i < audio.length; i++) {
  audio[i].setAttribute('id', i);
  console.log(audio[i]);
}
```

```html
<audio src="1.mp3"></audio>
<audio src="2.mp3"></audio>
<audio src="3.mp3"></audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
const matches = document.querySelectorAll("audio");
```

With this method, we are storing in a constant named *matches* all the elements in the DOM that have the tag .

Then you can probably add the ID, as a unique identifier:

```
const matches = document.querySelectorAll("audio");

matches.forEach((match, i) => match.id = i);
```

In the example, I am adding as ID property the iteration number (from 0 to X) for every audio element in the DOM.

This is the output:

[image: output of const matches]

So now you have an array of every audio element in the DOM with a unique identifier ready to be used

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? Using jQuery: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qdv7sr2k/)

```
for (var a = 0; a < $('audio').length; a++) { //Loops every audio element
   $('audio').eq(a).attr('id', "audioNum" + a); //Adds ID from loop index
}
```