# How Can I Add Ascending Data Values to Div Elements in For/Of Loop?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a for/of loop that iterates through an array inside an object.

I then create a div element, add a classList, then set the innerHTML to the iterator which creates 4 divs.

I am trying to set ascending data values (0-3) on each div using a for loop but it only assigns data value 3 to each div.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish my goal?

[DevTools view of elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfbUn.png)

```
function showQs() {
      const num = 4;
      index = Math.floor(questions.length - 1);
      pick = questions[index];
      questions.splice(index, 1);
      console.log(`${pick.question}`);
      questionSpot.innerHTML = `<h2>${pick.question}</h2>`;
     
      for (const i of pick.choice) {
        const choiceDiv = document.createElement('div');
       
        choiceDiv.classList = 'answerchoices';
        choiceDiv.innerHTML = i;
        console.log(choiceDiv);
        choiceSpot.appendChild(choiceDiv)
        for (var e = 0; e < num; e++) {
          console.log(e);
          console.log(choiceDiv);
          choiceDiv.setAttribute('data-guessvalue', e);
        }
     
      }
    
    }
```

Comment: I think this will help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65659203/how-to-assign-identifiers-to-all-html-elements-of-a-particular-type/65659424#65659424

Comment: Make a reproducible example if you want help.

Comment: Lol I was not being sarcastic. The solution you provided helped. Thanks again!